# WebApi optional parameter - is required?

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller (TasksController) with a get method like :

```
public IEnumerable<TimeUnitModel> Get(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string projectCode = "")
```

If I call

```
/api/tasks?startDate=2012%2F12%2F08&endDate=2012%2F12%2F15
```

the correct result is returned.

If I call

```
/api/tasks?startDate=2012%2F12%2F08&endDate=2012%2F12%2F15&projectCode=
```

then I get :

```
{"projectCode.String":"A value is required but was not present in the request."}
```

Any idea why this happens ?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
Here's what I have in the route config :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "tasks_get",
            routeTemplate: "api/tasks",
            defaults: new { controller = "tasks", projectCode = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Comment: @sirrocco I have seen similar behaviour to this before, on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006524/why-does-modelstate-isvalid-fail-for-my-apicontroller-method-that-has-nullable-p/12622152#12622152

Comment: P.s. projectCode is in the query string not the path and therefore not a route parameter - so you can remove optional parameter bit from config.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll also take a look in the framework just out of curiosity. And yes, you are correct about it not being a route parameter but I just had to try it :) .

Answer (score 3):

Your first call:
   `/api/tasks?startDate=2012%2F12%2F08&endDate=2012%2F12%2F15`
*is* how you call the method with an optional parameter (i.e. the parameter is optional, so you are not specifying it).  When you specify "&projectCode=" in the query string, you *are* specifying the parameter, and you're specifying it as *null*.  Since strings are nullable, the api assumes you *want* to send in a null value.  If you want the method to run with an empty string, just call it the way you were doing before without sending in that parameter at all.