# AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - A value is required but was not present in the request

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net5

I have a webapi controller like below:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(SampleDto))]
public IHttpActionResult GetSample(string name, string guid)
```

and the request take name and guid as query string like:
http://www.example.com/api/Controller1/GetSample?name=james&guid=

the guid is empty.

When I issue the request, there is an Error:

```
WARN  2018-09-29 07:04:21,361 [18   ] nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - Method arguments are not valid! See ValidationErrors for details.
Abp.Runtime.Validation.AbpValidationException: Method arguments are not valid! See ValidationErrors for details.
WARN  2018-09-29 07:04:21,361 [18   ] nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - There are 2 validation errors:
WARN  2018-09-29 07:04:21,361 [18   ] nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - A value is required but was not present in the request. (guid.String)
WARN  2018-09-29 07:04:21,361 [18   ] nHandling.AbpApiExceptionFilterAttribute - A value is required but was not present in the request. (guid.String)
```

Where can I change the validation rule?

Comment: you can declare the method as `public IHttpActionResult GetSample(string name, string guid = string.Empty)`, to make it optional

Comment: Is the breakpoint hitting this method ?

Comment: the method cannot be called at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebApi optional parameter - is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893793/webapi-optional-parameter-is-required)

Comment: Correct way: `http://www.example.com/api/Controller1/GetSample?name=james` without `&guid=`

Comment: solved if change client code which is not what I want.