# Web Api 2 : How to make ModelState recognize optional parameters?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I currently have this controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetByIdAndAnotherID([FromUri]int? id, [FromUri]int? AnotherId ){

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //From ApiController.ModelState
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access `/api/Home?id=&AnotherId=1` or `/api/Home?id=1&AnotherId=`, it returns the following error `A value is required but was not present in the request.` I have clearly indicated that `id` or `AnotherId` should be an optional value.

Why is the ModelState not valid? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `ModelState` in Web Api doesn't recognize this kind of parameter `?a=&b=`. Not exactly sure why but we need to [add a `[BinderType]` to `[FormUri]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12622152/3526156) like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetByIdAndAnotherID(
        [FromUri(BinderType = typeof(TypeConverterModelBinder))]int? ID = null,
        [FromUri(BinderType = typeof(TypeConverterModelBinder))]int? AnotherID = null){

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //From ApiController.ModelState
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The route that you have defined is:

`[Route("{id?}/{AnotherId?}")]`

which means you would call it as follows `/api/Home/0/1` where `0` would resolve to the value of `id` and `1` would resolve to the value of `AnotherId`.

I believe if you remove that route attribute and just leave the `[Route("")]` route attribute you should be able to call the method as you are expecting(`/api/Home?id=&AnotherId=1` or `/api/Home?id=1&AnotherId=`) and get the results you are expecting.

Comment: Removing it didn't work but thanks for the correction anyway. I have edited my question again.

Comment: @Mark Does your project also have MVC Controllers? I just tested this locally with a WebApi 2 project and it works as expected, no errors. You shouldn't need the BinderType. I would be interested to know what else you have in your project that is causing this issue.

Comment: It is a default Web API 2 project. Nothing has been added yet except that controller and of course, `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`. Maybe when we do a `/api/Home?&id=` in our get parameters, Web API expects a value to `id`. These urls work though; `/api/Home?id=1` and `/api/Home?AnotherId=2`